# How to write props properly in styled-components?

Tags: styled-components

I need to change `background` based on condition if `props.src` exist. First part works fine, but place where it has `props => props.src` not getting rendered properly.

[image]

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You only need `props.src` rather than the function `props => props.src` in your url:

```
background: ${props => props.src === "" ? "#eff1f2" : `url(${props.src}) no-repeat center`};
```

Styled components won’t execute the nested inner function so it just gets stringified.